# How to do this using collections/ stream api

Tags: java

I have this Requirement :
Construct each Doctor with their respective Appointments and return a doctorList. Input is Appointment List for whole Hospital.
What I have is the followings:

Two classes given with the following variables.

```
Class Appointment{
    
    
    String doctorName;
    DateTime startTime;
    DateTime endTime;
    String speciality;
        
    //Getters-Setters
}
```

Another Class :

```
Class Doctor{
    
    
    String name;
    String speciality;
    List <Appointment> appointments;
    
    //Getters-Setters
    
}
```

Requirement is :
Construct each Doctor with their respective Appointments and return a doctorList.
Input is Appointment List for whole Hospital.

Can some body tell what should be my approach?

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @SKM.CODER Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Use Map to maintain the appointments of each doctor. In the below code you can get the appointment details using the doctor's name.

`//appointments - input list

```
Map<String, List<Appointment>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Appointment app : appointments) {
        if(!map.containsKey(app.getDoctorName())) {
            List<Appointment> li = new ArrayList<>();
            li.add(app);
            map.put(app.getDoctorName(),li);
        } else {
            map.get(app.getDoctorName()).add(app);
        }       
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap.

HashMap<Doctor, ArrayList> doctorList = new HashMap<>();

Might not be a good idea in your case mainly because I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need match doctors with Appointment by both Speciality and Name, then:

```
        Map<String, List<Appointment>> map = appointmentList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getDoctorName() + e.getSpeciality()));

        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String doctorNameAndSpeciality : map.keySet()) {
            List<Appointment> appointments = map.get(doctorNameAndSpeciality);
            if (!appointments.isEmpty()) {
                Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
                Appointment appointment = appointments.get(0);
                doctor.setName(appointment.getDoctorName());
                doctor.setSpeciality(appointment.getSpeciality());
                doctor.addAllAppointments(appointments);
            }
        }
        return doctors;
```

if you need use only 'name', then just remove 'speciality'